# 2.5D Rendering QGIS

Tags: qgis, rendering

I want to render the sea chart of Florida in 2.5D, I have kept only the contour layer (line layer) and the outline of the area. I have removed all other layers. The map specification is US4FL44M.

Comment: what do you have in mind when saying 'render'? what is your goal, do you want a simple map with elevation details with 2.5D effect? I posted a possible solution for raster basemaps below, might be what you want.

Comment: Exactly what i want, a simple map with elevation details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have a few options here (a bit more detailed information on your goal would be nice...also, what did you do so far?), but in general and as the easiest way, 2,5D as a visual support for maps is achieved through Digital Elevation Model rasters, with one famous method being hillshading.
You need to interpolate a DEM from your contour layer as a start, and QGIS offers easy hillshading via the layer style properties (of raster layers).
Check the web for DEM styling, you'll see plenty of possibilities to get 2.5D visual impressions, also in conjunction with vector data.

Comment: I will try this.